# window.location.hash problems in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.location

I have a problem concerning a site I'm creating

```
<div id="footer"></div>    
<script>    
function preloadFunc()    
{    
window.location.hash = 'footer'
}
window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
</script>
```

Above is the piece of code (placed in the head, the div is positioned 15300px top) redirecting the page to the bottom before anything else gets loaded (I wanna start from bottom up). It works perfectly here for chrome/safari, but only seems to redirect in FF after a refresh. Is there a workaround for this?

(+ #div in the end of the url is not possible as redirecting a domain to a url#div seems to not work server side/cpanel. presumably because #div is not a directory)

Comment: When you refer to a function by name and follow that with `()`, that means you're *calling* the function. What you're assigning to `.onpaint` is the *return value* from the function call. Drop the `()`.

Comment: *"is the piece of code (placed in the head, the div is positioned 15300px top)"* So where is this code at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be

```
window.onpaint = preloadFunc;
```

Apparently Chrome/Safari have no problem understanding `location.hash = 'footer'` before footer element is available (or they preprender layout somehow), but Firefox has no idea that there will be element with the id `footer` soon. So it does nothing.

Comment: According to the code posted in the OP, the element with id "footer" comes *before* the `<script>` block.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, it explains everything. I was wondering why it works in Chrome.

Comment: I don't know. I wonder if there's something that happens at some later point in Firefox that effectively nullifies the hash setting?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about code block placement *is the piece of code (placed in the head, the div is positioned 15300px top)*. *"placed in the head"*?